# How expensive is high-volume Joda DateTime creation?

Tags: java, datetime, memory

I have an application that creates thousands of Joda [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects per second:

```
public void handleHighVolumeRequest(Foo foo) {
    DateTime dt = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
    foo.setDateTime(dt);
    // do other stuff with 'foo' and 'dt'
}
```

I'm using default JDK6 garbage collection (PS Scavenge and PS MarkSweep).  Non-default memory settings are `-Xmx768M`.

Is there a non-trivial cost to creating all these `DateTime` objects for short-lived (100s of millisecond) requests?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#performance
It seems to perform good.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are short lived if the space between you minor GC is much longer than they live, ie. they die in the Eden space most of the time.

The objects are non-trivial, but it is all relative.  Most likely each one is costing you in the order of micro-second and using up a few hundred bytes of your Eden space.

If your are seeing premature promotion and short intervals between minor GC, you can try increasing your Eden size.  e.g. 8 GB is not unreasonable.  If you are getting a minor GC every 0.5 seconds you you would prefer every 2 seconds, try increasing the young generation by 4x.

If you just want the start of the day, you could do this.

```
long startOfDayGMT = System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY * MILLIS_PER_DAY;
```

This will take about 50 nano-seconds and creates no garbage.

Technically, computers only support GMT, not UTC which has leap seconds.